# Does a plaintiff have standing in an action for cost of suit in cases where a fee waiver is granted to plaintiff?

Tags: united-states, california, damages, fees, legal-fees

Or is it the court who will have to order the defendant to pay for the fees it effectively advances to the plaintiff?

---

**Background**

As suggested per the comments:

> “According to the California info sheet, "If you win your case in the trial court: In most circumstances the other side will be ordered to pay your waived fees and costs to the court."”

I could think of multiple reasons that would seem reasonable to praying for costs of suit:

1. Since financial circumstances may change during the course of a suit, a plaintiff may become capable of paying the court fees, and by the end of a trial, they may have actually paid, at least partially, the court fees — may be in that case the Complaint needs to be amended which has its downsides, and may or may not need the defendants consent, but I would imagine you would need standing in the matter;
2. Based on the California info sheet on fee waivers, it does not seem impossible that in the exceptions when the court would not order the other party to pay, whatever they may be, the court may (or may not) deem you to owe the court fees, and it may be beneficial to have had an action sought for them therefore;
3. Very simply: If one doesn’t do that at the begging even if they have their fees waived from the outset, I don’t see it difficult to imagine that one may lose their right to eventually not be liable for those waived fees.

Comment: Fee waivers waive the court fees, don't they? If so, how/why would they have any relation to other costs incurred by the plaintiff?

Comment: @Greendrake: I thought that too, but according to the [California info sheet](https://www.courts.ca.gov/documents/fw001info.pdf), "If you win your case in the trial court: In most circumstances the other side will be ordered to pay your waived fees and costs to the court."  I am not sure if that answers OP's question, but at least it could maybe be edited into the question for context.

Comment: @Greendrake No, they are basically advanced — if your financials improve or become able to pay, you have to let the court know in 5 days. If you settle an action, you may be ordered to pay out of it. But of course if you prevail, that money should not be paid by you for any action where you do. The question, to oversimplify it, is who has a duty to pay the money? The plaintiff, and of course they can sue the defendant, and likely will prevail on it; or the plaintiff will not have to go after the defendant and act as a middle man. Can you elaborate on the second question?

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks, I added that information, that makes the potential complexity of the question clearer.

Comment: Can you clearly define what costs/fees the question is about? Does it include lawyer's fees for example?

Comment: FWIW, this isn't really a question of standing. Standing goes to the question of whether the plaintiff had an actual injury in the underlying lawsuit. There is a legitimate procedural question to answer, but it isn't really a standing question.

Comment: @Greendrake Cost of suit claims do not include in California, and probably in any states in the U.S., attorney's fees. It's a separate claim for moneys spent for e.g. filing fees, court fees, printing cost etc.

Comment: @ohwilleke That was, initially when written, at the heart of the question: I was not sure whether or not when you prevail, you will owe the court if they waived you fees since it was unclear whether the court would deem you to owe that money, or automatically deem the other party to owe the court despite it initially paid on your behalf. It seems, generally, that the court does not deem the prevailing, fee-waived party to owe them, but the non-prevailing who didn't. There for, there wouldn't be injury — or at least how I understand it so far.

Comment: @ohwilleke In other words: Who suffered the injury of having to pay court fees, the court or the plaintiff? Or at least how I understood it.

Comment: So I think your question is as follows: in order to have the court order the defendant to pay the fee if you win, is it necessary for you to have included a demand for the fee in your initial prayer for relief?  And if it is, what happens if you didn't include it?  If that's your question, I agree that it doesn't seem to have anything to do with standing.

Comment: I mean, a question could made that way, too. It may be that the exception only relates to the discretion of the court to not collect, and the fee-waived plaintiff never incurred those fees, and never suffered those injuries therefore they have no standing. The question is spelled out correctly. (Although, I've been thinking about a feature that could generate some serious visitor activity on SE's)